# Can a Trezor seed be used in any other HD wallet?

Tags: security, bip32-hd-wallets, trezor

[Trezor FAQ](http://doc.satoshilabs.com/trezor-user/securitybestpractices.html#keep-your-recovery-seed-safe-from) says

> If you do not use a passphrase, your recovery seed is all that is needed to access your bitcoins.

If you do not use a passphrase, can the Trezor seed be used to recreate a [hierarchical deterministic wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Deterministic_Wallet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Trezor uses the [BIP0032](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki) standard to derive your keys from the seed. That means you can use any BIP0032-compatible client for recovery, or you can even use them simultaneously (but be aware of the security implications - you don't want it to leak, otherwise it beats the whole Trezor purpose).

For example, [Electrum](https://electrum.org/) works great with HD wallets, but I'm sure you can find other clients as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Yesterday MultiBitHD committed support for Trezor. I think MulitBitHD is still in Beta, but you could probably still try it out.