# I can recover my Trezor funds without a Trezor?

Tags: trezor

Consider that I have my seed phrase.

If I lost my Trezor and can't buy another, I have a way to access my funds without a Trezor ?

Comment: You can use any BIP0032-compatible client for recovery [https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/31992/can-a-trezor-seed-be-used-in-any-other-hd-wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/31992/can-a-trezor-seed-be-used-in-any-other-hd-wallet)

Comment: Recovery from seed phrase is BIP39, but generally all BIP32 wallets use BIP39.